# Why is google console showing url as anchor text instead of actual anchor text?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, django

I have deployed a website using Django. This is my very first app so still trying to learn.

So I was checking my SEO progress and ended up checking my google search console and saw this:

[image: Google console top linking page]

The very first URL in top linking text pertains to `https://www.example.com/by-election-p/provincial-assembly/1063-by-election-2022/`. I am trying to figure out why google console is showing url text instead of actual anchor text. The same thing is happening with rest of the top linking text so I really fell that I am doing something wrong but can't figure our what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module "*Top linking text*" is part of the "*External links*" (backlinks) section in Google Search Console.

So maybe other websites are actually using your URL as the link anchor when they link to you? For my personal website, for which I have done zero link building, it is very similar. Three of the top five link anchors are actually URLs.

If you use the report "*Top linked pages*", you can easily find a list of example URLs on other websites, linking to one of your URLs. Click on them and check the anchor texts. I am sure you will see that this is just how other websites link to you.